# Hyperledger Fabric transaction speed

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, ibm-blockchain

According to official website the transaction speed in fabric is supposed to be 3k tr/sec. But on running byfn  I am getting 8 tr/sec,which is much less,i get the fact that there would be a few considerations for that speed but even then isn't it too less??

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, it depends on your hardware, your docker cluster, the number of nodes, the resources per node, the block length, the complexity of the transaction logic, the endorsement policies, the ratio of concurrent operations over the same documents, etc. It's software, not magic. Don't expect to run the simplest deployment on your development laptop and reach thousands of tx/s. When a company invests in IT infrastructure and people, it's not because it has too much money.

Here you have some reference benchmarking: https://hyperledger.github.io/caliper-benchmarks/fabric/performance/1.4.0/nodeJS/nodeSDK/configuration/.

Comment: Just so you know @kekomal, the document you linked 404s.

Comment: A more recent evaluation of speed for version 2.1.0 can be found here: https://hyperledger.github.io/caliper-benchmarks/fabric/performance/2.1.0/nodeContract/nodeSDK/configuration/